# How Do I show advanced Date filters for Events?

Tags: entries, date, datetime

I am trying to setup an events section similar to that of Yelp's Events.  They have a listing of all the upcoming events and have filters on the side for "Today, Tomorrow" etc...

I received help from Brandon Kelly and will be posting my answer below.

Comment: This seems like a valuable Q&A, Mark. I think the question could be better if it was more descriptive and self-contained, leaving room for other answers if any are so bold as to compete with Mr. Kelly. I enjoy pretending I'm two different people asking and answering, though I can follow up on that with a therapist.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to Brandon Kelly's help I now have Events being filtered by my custom date field called `eventDate` by doing the following:

```
{% set day = date(craft.request.getSegment(2)) %}
{% set nextDay = day|date_modify('+1 day') %}
{% set events = craft.entries.eventDate('and, >= '~day|date('Y-m-d')~', <'~nextDay|date('Y-m-d')) %}
```

I have some links in my side bar that append the appropriate Date to the URL:

```
<a href="{{ url('events/'~now|date('Y-m-d')) }}">Today</a>
<a href="{{ url('events/'~nextDay|date('Y-m-d')) }}">Tomorrow</a>
```

And finally I just loop that through like so:

```
{% for block in events %}{% endfor %}
```

I hope someone else can find this as handy as I did through Brandon's help!

Comment: This awesome and a great example of Twig's awesomeness.

Comment: This thread will come in handy as we need to do something similar on the site we just started building. Thanks for posting it!