# Or element criteria model filters

Tags: elementcriteriamodel

Im trying to do an OR filter for craft.entries and not sure of the syntax

so like this

```
{% set startedThisYear = craft.entries.find({ section: 'exhibitions', startDate: ">= " ~startDate, startDate: "<= " ~endDate, order:'startDate desc'}) %}
```

if i wanted it to be

startDate: ">= " ~startDate or startDate: "<= " ~endDate

??

Comment: Keith, see my [question here](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/1948/125) for a similar problem that I solved using a workaround collecting entry IDs.

Comment: The 'duplicate' is actually a much more complicated scenario  that might actually confuse people — I'm not sure if it's such a good match. But not a big deal. Problem solved.

Comment: Yea I agree, I dont think the answer they gave in the "match" is the right answer here.  What I was looking for was the syntax to do 'and' and 'or' conditionals in the craft.entries. queries, where as the other questions solution was to do multiple queries and combine them together.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that you actually want to use 'and' rather than 'or'. 'Or' would return all entries. This is also assuming that you have predefined the 'startDate' and 'endDate' variables.

```
{% set params = {
    section: 'exhibitions',
    startDate: 'and, >= ' ~ startDate ~ ', <= ' ~ endDate,
    order:'startDate desc'
} %}

{% set startedThisYear = craft.entries(params) %}
```

If you haven't already done so, you may need to format 'startDate' and 'endDate' variables first.

```
startDate: 'and, >= ' ~ startDate|date('Y-m-d') ~ ', <= ' ~ endDate|date('Y-m-d')
```

See this answer for [another example](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/168/how-do-i-show-advanced-date-filters-for-events).